# Generate .sass automatically and livereload

Tags: gulp

```
var gulp =require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass')
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    del = require('del');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
   return sass('./public/styles/sass/style.sass')
       .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/styles/css/'))
});

//clean
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['./public/styles/css'], cb)
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Create LiveReload server

  gulp.watch('./public/styles/', ['styles'])
  // Watch any files in dist/, reload on change
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(['./public/styles']).on('change', livereload.changed);
});


gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch'], function() {

});
```

Kept on having to type "gulp styles" over again and again. Couldn't get it to generate from .sass to .css automatically without typing repeatedly. How to make it generate automatically?

Another thing is live reload. It seems not to be working when testing on chrome browse with extension live reload. Not sure where it went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You watch is wrong.

```
gulp.watch('./public/styles/', ['styles'])
```

should be something like

```
gulp.watch('./public/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles'])
```

This will cause the `styles` task to run whenever a SASS file is updated within `public/styles/`, even if it's nested within child directories.

You could do something similar for livereload. I suggest looking at something like [BrowserSync](http://www.browsersync.io/) though - it doesn't require a browser plugin and "just works" once configured.